# Typescript transpiled Javascript does not include properties

Tags: typescript

My transpiled Javascript for my client side models do not include the properties from the Typescript files.

These properties are never directly set as they are parsed and mapped from JSON so I thought perhaps the compiler was being clever and optimising the code to remove unused properties but I don't see any options to turn such behaviour off so perhaps something else.

One of my models as an example:

## RfidData.ts

```
import { TimeModel } from "./Model";

export class RfidData extends TimeModel {
  DeviceId: string;
  Transponders: string[];
}
```

## RfidData.js (compiled output)

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const Model_1 = require("./Model");
class RfidData extends Model_1.TimeModel {
}
exports.RfidData = RfidData;
//# sourceMappingURL=RfidData.js.map
```

As you can see the two properties `DeviceId` and `Transponders` don't make it into the transpiled output.

## .tsconfig (for reference)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "Client/js/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE -- Further Discussion

After a good discussion there is another issue here which is that types are stripped after being transpiled, type erasure as jcalz points out. So mapping JSON through with an interface or setting the properties manually doesn't solve the issue if you have typed properties. For instance a `Date` is left as any in an underlying class so you cannot access any relevant properties, its left as a string on the JS.

Is there anyway to maintain types in ES6 transpiled from TypeScript? Otherwise this question was rather academic. :(

Comment: This may be an optimization of the compiler. Do you have class methods or constructors that use these properties?

Comment: Yes they are read but not directly set. They are parsed from JSON then cast to the relevant type. Seems like a strange optimisation as they are being read, and parsing models from JSON is quite a common practice.

Comment: @GerardWilkinson never, ever use classes to represent the types of objects returned by `JSON.parse`. It's an exceedingly dangerous practice and results in fragile, misleading code. Ward Bell is not God, take his recommendations with a grain of salt. The angular style guide is hands-down the worst way to learn typescript.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Why? Surely relying on the contents of any parsed result undefined object is equally dangerous. What other way is there to parse have typed objects from for instance a web socket?

Comment: @GerardWilkinson consider `x instanceof Y` will always be false but is legal because of class usage. Use `interface` not `class` for DTO

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't actually do that because I was aware that even once cast if it is not of the expected type you just have extraneous properties hanging off the instance. However what do you suggest to have some kind of type checking? Construct an instance from the JSON object? EDIT: Yes you are probably right it should be an interface.

Comment: Use an interface. Also while you may know that it's not possible, someone else you work with me not know that and you may also forget if you use the same class in another context but it gets passed back and forth.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That would still happen with an interface... Anyway I take your point that you cannot guarantee this is indeed the type you are expecting, therefore defeats the point of type checking.

Comment: @GerardWilkinson no that isn't my point. My point is that you can't use an interface in an instance of check. Also no one looking at the type signature of the method knows that you aren't in fact instantiating a class from the result and they may well attempt such a check

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have no idea what you are suggesting then. Can you post a more detailed answer? I think this is a good discussion.

Comment: @GerardWilkinson I'll do so when I get some time but what I'm suggesting is that you write `interface Y {...} const x = <Y>JSON.parse(r);`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry I understood that the first time. My comment was confusing. Apologies, I meant to type check / interface with a class. Interface is obviously the correct approach here. Thanks again.

Comment: @AluanHaddad After migrating to interfaces I forgot that these are stripped at compile time. So for instance Date are not read as Dates but instead are strings, causing errors in the output JS. Using interfaces only really helps for the TypeScript code and doesn't provide any type guarding in the transpiled JS.

Comment: @GerardWilkinson but that's how you were using the type in the first place. Since you weren't instantiating the class it didn't have any effect on the emitted code. If you need to perform conversions then you need to call a function or instantiate a class, both of which will result in type inference. Because the types will be inferred you won't need to use them as annotations anyway and they won't be misleading if they are classes

Comment: But then you're talking about writing a custom serialization layer. In other words you have to handle them on both incoming and outgoing requests and that gets complicated

Comment: I don't think I am. What I am saying is the line `const x = <Y>JSON.parse(r);` effectively doesn't do anything as the transpiled Javascript has stripped this. How do we maintain typed objects, `Object.assign`?

Comment: You need to post your code that does the serialization and deserialization and we can maybe help make it type-safe.  TypeScript doesn't alter the runtime behavior of `JSON.parse()` so in particular it will not deserialize anything into a `Date` object.  You have to write code that does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript [erases](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) all type information when it transpiles to JavaScript.  In your case, the property declarations aren't setting any values, so they are erased too.  I'm not sure why you want to see them at runtime if you aren't setting their values, but you probably have your reasons.

If you really want to see properties in the JavaScript, then you can [initialize them](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) to values:

```
export class RfidData extends TimeModel {
  DeviceId: string = ""; 
  Transponders: string[] = [];
}
```

transpiles to

```
class RfidData extends Model_1.TimeModel {
    constructor() {
        this.DeviceId = "";
        this.Transponders = [];
    }
}
```

If you can't think of reasonable initial values, you can set them to `undefined` or `void 0` (and if you have `--strictNullChecks` on you will have to use `undefined!` or the like).

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Excellent answer. It's worth noting that when the Class Fields proposal gets implemented this behaviour will probably change to default initialize each with undefined in the emitted code.

Comment: One more thing, I don't think it matters in the OP's case because I don't believe he's even instantiating the class

Comment: Thanks all. @AluanHaddad is right I am not instantiating the class. I am using the class to type check parsed JSON from a web socket. Open to suggestions for better approaches but this works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed the question should say transpiled not compiled!

Comment: @GerardWilkinson transpilation is just a kind of compilation (source -> source) I wouldn't worry about it too much :) but you are correct

Comment: Is there anyway to maintain types in ES6 transpiled code? Otherwise there isn't really any point in mapping this back to a class. `Date` is particularly annoying as its always getting considered as a string.